# X? regex quantifier doesn't work as expected (by me)

Tags: java, regex

Input string:

- `aaa---foo---ccc---ddd`
- `aaa---bar---ccc---ddd`
- `aaa---------ccc---ddd`

Regex: `aaa.*(foo|bar)?.*ccc.*(ddd)`

This regex doesn't find first group (foo|bar) in any cases. It always returns `null` for capture group 1.
My question is why and how can I avoid that.

It's very oversimplified example of my regex for just demonstrating. It works if I remove `?` quantifier but input string can be without this group at all (`aaa---------ccc---ddd`) and I still need to determine if it is `foo` or `bar` or `null`. But group 1 is always `null`.

Page with this regex and test strings: http://fiddle.re/45c766

Comment: Can we see how you are using this regex? Could you post some code example?

Comment: Is `"aaafoo------ccc---ddd"` also correct string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's why it doesn't work: When you have `.*` in a pattern, the matcher's algorithm is to try to match as many characters as it can to make the rest of the pattern work.  In this case, if it tries starting with the entire remainder of the string as `.*` and removing one character until it matches, it finds that (for `"aaa---foo---ccc---ddd"`) it will work to have `.*` match 9 characters; then `(foo|bar)?` doesn't match anything, which is OK because it's optional; and the next `.*` matches 0 characters, and then the rest of the pattern matches.  So that's the one it selects.

The reason changing `.*` to `.*?`:

```
aaa.*?(foo|bar)?.*?ccc.*(ddd)
```

doesn't work is that the matcher does the same thing in reverse.  It starts with a 0-character match and then figures out if it can make the pattern work.  When it tries this, it will find that it works to make `.*?` match 0 characters; then `(foo|bar)?` doesn't match anything; then the second `.*?` matches 9 characters; then the rest of the pattern matches `ccc---ddd`.  So either way, it won't do what you want.

There are a couple solutions in the answers, both involving lookahead.  Here's another solution:

```
aaa.*(foo|bar).*ccc.*(ddd)|aaa.*ccc.*(ddd)
```

This basically checks for two patterns, in order; first it checks to see if there's a pattern with `foo|bar` in it, and if that doesn't match, it will then search for the other possibility, without `foo|bar`.  This will always find `foo|bar` if it's there.

All of these solutions involve rather difficult-to-read regexes, though.  This is how I might code it:

```
Pattern pat1 = Pattern.compile("aaa(.*)ccc.*ddd");
Pattern pat2 = Pattern.compile("foo|bar");

Matcher m1 = pat1.matcher(source);
String foobar;
if (m1.matches()) {
    Matcher m2 = pat2.matcher(m1.group(1));
    if (m2.find()) {
        foobar = m2.group(0);
    } else {
        foobar = null;
    }
}
```

Often, attempting to use one whiz-bang regex to solve a problem results in less-readable (and possibly less-efficient) code than just breaking the problem into parts.

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer. This is really what I want!

Answer (score 3):

Change your regex to the below if you want to capture the inbetween `foo` or `bar` strings.

```
aaa(?:(?!foo|bar).)*(foo|bar)?.*?ccc.*?(ddd)
```

Because the `.*` would also eats up the in-between strings `foo` or `bar`, you could use `(?:(?!foo|bar).)*` instead of that. This `(?:(?!foo|bar).)*` regex would match any character but not of `foo` or `bar` zero or more times.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xH3iL5/1)

```
String s = "aaa---foo---ccc---ddd\n" +
           "aaa---bar---ccc---ddd\n" +
           "aaa---------ccc---ddd";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("aaa(?:(?!foo|bar).)*(foo|bar)?.*?ccc.*?(ddd)");
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
 }
```

**Output:**

```
foo
bar
null
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
.{3}\-{3}(.{3})\-{3}.{3}\-{3}(.{3})
```

Comment: It's very oversimplified example of my regex for just demonstrating. Real input is much more unpredictable. Not just three dashes. :)

Comment: What can the input be?
Is it awlays in groups of 3?